# Android video not stretching to full screen?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

i am trying to play a video using videoview so as to cover the whole screen below the actionbar, it stretches vertically but horizontally stays in the middle with black area on both sides.. could anyone fix the issue?

```
public void playVideo(String videoname)
    {
        VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + videoname);

        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        vd.setMediaController(mc);

        vd.setVideoURI(uri);
        vd.start();
    }
```

xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"            
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <VideoView
                        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:gravity="center"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is the video developed at the correct aspect ratio?  If it's, say, 640x480, it likely won't stretch to widescreen width.

Comment: it's 480x360 but could there be anyway around ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Stretching a video clip requires additional rendering resources.